# ListView Cell Dragging and Rearranging Using DevByte Code not working in Lollipop

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to implement ListView cell Dragging and Rearranging using DevByte Code. But This code is not working in Lollipop.
Please Help.
Link for the code is 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q

CLick on SHOW MORE  then on the code to download the code .

Answer (score 1):

On DynamicListView search for

```
mobileView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
switchView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

And replace to this:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
   mobileView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   switchView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: thank u for your reply.. i have already solved it in the same way you did .. :)